# Jax-rsClient Program for http and https

Tags: java, http, client, jax-rs

I'm studying an application developed by our company. It uses the Apache HttpClient . In the source code it uses the HttpsClient class also. In Some examples it use CloseableHttpClient instead of HttpClient..
 questions:
How to create client for https url?
if I am using CloseableHttpClient will it work with https urls or not?
HttpsClient and httpClient will work with https url?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific client for https, you just need to change the URL you use to https instead of http.

If you have very specific ssl requirements (like needing to accept a self signed certificate) you can configure the ssl settings of your http client. Here's a nice tutorial to explain how that's done https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_httpclient/apache_httpclient_custom_ssl_context.htm